# Having a blank textbox crashes the program when i press the login button

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Beginner programmer. I have a login button, it works completely fine when I enter the right credentials, but when I click the login button while having an empty textbox the program crashes and gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". I tried using != null in the else if but that didn't work either. So my question is how would I be able to get an empty textbox displaying "Please enter a valid username and/or password" instead of crashing the program? Thanks!

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Entities2 db = new Entities2();
    foreach (var usert in db.Teachers)
    {
        if (usert.TID == Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && usert.Password == txtPassword.Text)
        {
            Teach teacher = new Teach();
            teacher.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (usert.TID != Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && usert.Password != txtPassword.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) expects a valid string. An empty string will throw an exception

Comment: Yep! But how would i get around that?

Comment: Just use try-catch statement

Comment: You convert the string to int a maximum of `2 * db.Teachers.Count()`.  You only have to convert it once.  Oh, to be wet behind the ears again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       if(txtLogin.Text!="" && txtPassword.Text!="")
       {
          Entities2 db = new Entities2();
          foreach (var usert in db.Teachers)
          {
             if (usert.TID == Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) &&  usert.Password == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Teach teacher = new Teach();
                teacher.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (usert.TID != Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && usert.Password != txtPassword.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
            }
        }
      else
      {
         if(txtLogin.Text=="")
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Username");
         }
         else if(txtPassword.Text=="") 
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a  Password");
         }
      }
    }
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a  Valid Username and/or Password");
    }
}
```

And moreover this is not proper way to check and match the UserName Password. You can instead use the following approach

```
if(txtLogin.Text!="")
   {
      Entities2 db = new Entities2();
      Teacher Tobj=db.Teachers.where(x=>x.TID==Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && x.Password==txtPassword.Text).SingleOrDefault();
        if (Tobj!=null)
        {
            Teach teacher = new Teach();
            teacher.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
        }
   }
```

Comment: That will fail if a user enters anything else than a number

Comment: that will be caught in catch block. this piece of code is just to be replaced with the first if block code in the above code.

Comment: Then why do you test for an empty string if that would get caught in the exception handler as well? Anyway, you should never abuse exceptions to handle expected user input

Comment: Ok Sir , ofcourse this code could be more improved, but i am just trying to quickly convey to  the user that the foreach command it's code is using where its checks against every row in db to match for the username and password, and for every non matching row it shows the message boxes of Invalid UserName Alerts can be a not required functionality. I understand your point though.

Answer (score 2):

Check if Textbox is "" before anything...
See below:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtLogin.Text != "")
    {

        Entities2 db = new Entities2();
        foreach (var usert in db.Teachers)
        {
             if (usert.TID == Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && usert.Password == txtPassword.Text)
             {
                  Teach teacher = new Teach();
                  teacher.ShowDialog();
             }
             else if (usert.TID != Convert.ToInt32(txtLogin.Text) && usert.Password != txtPassword.Text)
             {
                  MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
             }
        }           
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a try parse. If it fails to parse, it will return false and you can do some error handling (thanks Phil).

```
int userId = 0;
if(int.TryParse(txtLogin.Text, out userId)){
   // err handling
}
```

Comment: No need to set useId to some "impossible value". int.TryParse() will return false if it fails so you can simply do: `if (int.TryParse(txtLogin.Text,out userId) {..}`

Comment: Totally forgot about that, I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        <body of your btnLogin_Click()>
    } 
    catch(FormatException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
    }
    catch(Exception ex2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex2.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the entered user ID first, like this:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId;

    if (int.TryParse(txtLogin.Text, out userId))
    {
       Entities2 db = new Entities2();
       foreach (var usert in db.Teachers)
       {
           if (usert.TID == userId && usert.Password == txtPassword.Text)
           {
              Teach teacher = new Teach();
              teacher.ShowDialog();
           }
           else
           {
              MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Username and/or Password");
           }
       }
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid User ID");

    }
}
```